# Jquery click event targeting more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Codepen is here](http://codepen.io/modermo/pen/vLVJzd?editors=0110)

I have two triggers on an image. General behaviour:

- When I click a trigger, it should reveal a small context box (got this working)
- When I click outside of the context box OR the trigger, it should disappear (got this working)
- **When I click another trigger, if there is another trigger/context box that is already active/open, it should close the other one and open the recently click one (not working)**

Here's the html:

```
<span class='pulse-button' id="button-1"></span>

<div class="content-box context-closed tabs" id="tabs1">
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $(".pulse-button").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if( $(".pulse-button").not(this).hasClass("pulse-button-active")){
      $(".pulse-button").not(this).removeClass("pulse-button-active");
      $(".pulse-button").not(this).next().addClass("context-closed");
    }else{
      $(this).addClass("pulse-button-active");  
      $(this).next().removeClass("context-closed");
    };
  });

  $("body").click(function(evt){
    if(evt.target.class == "content-box")
      return;
    if($(evt.target).closest('.content-box').length)
          return;
    if( $(".pulse-button").hasClass("pulse-button-active")){
      $(".pulse-button").removeClass("pulse-button-active");
      $(".pulse-button").next().addClass("context-closed");
    };
  });

  $( "#tabs1,#tabs2" ).tabs();
});
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `else` in your `.pulse-button` click. Because the code in `else` block should be executed either any `.pulse-button` has class `pulse-button-active` or not. Change the your click event like following.

```
$(".pulse-button").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(".pulse-button").not(this).hasClass("pulse-button-active")) {
        $(".pulse-button").not(this).removeClass("pulse-button-active");
        $(".pulse-button").not(this).next().addClass("context-closed");
    }
    $(this).addClass("pulse-button-active");  
    $(this).next().removeClass("context-closed");
});
```

#### [UPDATED PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RreyrV?editors=0110)

Comment: I just realized that I mistyped something – it appears that if you click the trigger with it's companion context box open, it won't close the context box, whereas it should. 

So, clicking anywhere but the context box **OR clicking the trigger should close it**... Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: [Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/modermo/pen/MKPGrN?editors=0010)

Ok, so I've found the fix to have the context box close if you hit it's trigger... you gave the click function toggle the class rather than add or remove it... Code: `$(this).addClass("pulse-button-active");  $(this).next().removeClass("context-closed");` **to** `$(this).toggleClass("pulse-button-active");  
    $(this).next().toggleClass("context-closed");`